# Can we have a mifare tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

We have quite a few questions with this, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=mifare+is%3Aq, it's a particular technology people are free to fool around and with a wide professional impact,

Can we have `mifare` the tag? :)

Comment: Huh? What's a "mifare"?  No, I'm not going to follow a link to get information pertinent to the question.

Comment: @OlinLathrop sorry, I assumed people who knew about it would know about it and those who don't know about it wouldn't even bother with the question, I'll give more details about the technology involved in case I will ask for more tags in the future (doubtful, but still :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create new tags on EE.SE, you need [300 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95496/reputation-required-to-create-my-own-tag).

I somewhat agree a Mifare<sup>1</sup> tag could eventually make sense. We have a few questions relating to this already. There are many many tags much less relevant than this that have been created. And there is also already a [desfire](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desfire) tag, a [iso14443](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iso14443) tag, etc...

**But**

You have to realize that tags here don't have the same role as on the Stack Overflow site, for example. On SO, people are using tags to filter down the questions because there are thousands of question ranging from programming (in any kind of language: mainstream or esoteric, and in any kind of environment: desktop, mainframe, mobile, embedded), to database, source control, ... anything. If there were no tags, SO would be unuseable.

On the other hand, on EE.SE, although the range of technologies and domains is still very wide, there are much less question. Nobody would filter the questions on "mifare" only: you'll see four questions each year. And people who know mifare, also know how other contactless technologies work, more generally.

So what makes sense is to choose a more general tag for your question, such as the [nfc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfc) tag.

And it doesn't really matter if there is a mifare tag or not. For such a tiny domain (because it is just a tiny field in the whole electronics area, although I agree Mifare is widely used in corporations), if people want to search such questions, they search by text, not by tags.

---

<sup>1. Note to people who don't know what Mifare is: it is a protocol used for contactless smart card communication (NFC). And I agree this should have been mentioned in OP's question from the start.</sup>